# Unable to scrape data on results list using scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am currently trying to scrape the links to the cars on this [page](http://www.carzone.ie/used-cars/page/1).

I have ran this xpath command on the chrome console to return the links of each cars

```
$x('//div[@class="vehicle-make-model"]/h3/a/@href')
```

However, when I try to use the same xpath, whilst using the scrapy shell command it does not return any of the links. This is the code I run for the scrapy shell command

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="vehicle-make-model"]/h3/a/@href')
```

Can somebody point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPaths that work in Chrome are run on top of the DOM that is built with JavaScript.
That's why sometimes one thing works in Chrome but does not work in scrapy shell.

This is the case in the page you linked. If you check out the source of the page (right-click and choose "View Page Source" or hit Ctrl-U), you will see the same data that Scrapy gets.

In this particular case, the data seems to be all in one JSON block, so you can extract the JSON code out and parse it using python's JSON module, with something like:

```
import json
raw_json = response.xpath(
    "//script[contains(., 'window.jsonData')]/text()"
).re('window.jsonData\s*=\s*(.+);$')[0]
json_data = json.loads(raw_json)
```

Then you can use the data in the `json_data` to build the next requests or scrape whatever you need.

In case there wasn't an easily parseable JSON, another option would be to use the [js2xml](https://github.com/redapple/js2xml) library to parse the JavaScript into a XML that you would be able to scrape using XPath.